# Entity Framework connection string issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string

I am receiving the following error which I believe is a problem with my connection string on GoDaddy. I've copied from an example on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't seem to work.  The first part of the stack trace that I'm getting is:

> [MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.]
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String
>   assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry,
>   MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +2184231

I have a solution with only one project and, of course, the edmx is in that project.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="FCGUIDE_Entities"
         connectionString="
            metadata=res://*/CoreModel.csdl|res://*/CoreModel.ssdl|res://*/CoreModel.msl;
            provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
            provider connection string='
                Data Source=susanbfarrar.db.9319451.hostedresource.com;
                Initial Catalog=susanbfarrar;       
                integrated security=False;
                multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                App=EntityFramework; 
                User ID=*****;
                Password=*****
                Database=*****;'"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you replace ' with `&quot;` and try it again?

```
<add name="FCGUIDE_Entities"
         connectionString="
            metadata=res://*/CoreModel.csdl|res://*/CoreModel.ssdl|res://*/CoreModel.msl;
            provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
            provider connection string=&quot;
                Data Source=susanbfarrar.db.9319451.hostedresource.com;
                Initial Catalog=susanbfarrar;       
                integrated security=False;
                multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                App=EntityFramework; 
                User ID=*****;
                Password=*****
                Database=*****;&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You already have **Initial Catalog**, so remove **Database**

```
Password=*****Database=*****;&quot;
```

Like this -

```
Password=*****;&quot;
```

Comment: `Password=*****;&quot;` is correct. *Please make sure that you can connect to local DB using the same connection string just by replacing just **Data Source**, **User ID** and **Password**.* [Troubleshooting Entity Framework Connection Strings](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/)